# Debsecan doesn't show pending updates from Debian-Security

Tags: debian, apt, software-updates

I'm using debsecan to install security updates in my Debian jessie box. I thought that after installing all the packages reported I shouldn't have any pending updatess from Debian-Security repo but it isn't like that:

```
#: debsecan --suite jessie --format packages --only-fixed
#: 
#: apt-get --simulate upgrade | grep "Debian-Security"
Inst libapt-inst1.5 [1.0.9.8.3] (1.0.9.8.4 Debian:8.9/oldstable, Debian-Security:8/oldstable [amd64])
Inst libsoup2.4-1 [2.48.0-1] (2.48.0-1+deb8u1 Debian-Security:8/oldstable [amd64])
Inst libsoup-gnome2.4-1 [2.48.0-1] (2.48.0-1+deb8u1 Debian-Security:8/oldstable [amd64])
Inst libnet-dns-perl [0.81-2] (0.81-2+deb8u1 Debian:8.9/oldstable, Debian-Security:8/oldstable [amd64])
Conf libapt-inst1.5 (1.0.9.8.4 Debian:8.9/oldstable, Debian-    Security:8/oldstable [amd64])
Conf libsoup2.4-1 (2.48.0-1+deb8u1 Debian-Security:8/oldstable [amd64])
Conf libsoup-gnome2.4-1 (2.48.0-1+deb8u1 Debian-Security:8/oldstable [amd64])
Conf libnet-dns-perl (0.81-2+deb8u1 Debian:8.9/oldstable, Debian-Security:8/oldstable [amd64])
#:
```

I can't figure out why debsecan is not reporting those packages:

```
#: debsecan --suite jessie --format packages | grep "libapt\|libsoup\|libnet-dns"
#:
```

Any hint? Thanks.

Comment: Just in case you wonder, those packages are not whitelisted in debsecan.